# Storing a previous value of element of array

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I want to print firstly value of arr[0] equaled 1 and than print changed value of arr[0] equaled 5, but I can't figure out how to do that (even tried with debugger).

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    array<int, 4> arr{ 1,2,3,4 };
    int* ptr = &arr[0];
    arr[0] = 5;
    int** p = &ptr;
    cout << *ptr << endl;
    cout << **p << endl;
}
```

Comment: when you create a pointer to a memory location and than change it , the value of both pointer and the location change not matter how many time you change it .

Comment: Why don't you simply store its value in another variable?

Comment: Why are you using pointers for this at all? You should not use a pointer. `int prevVal = arr[0];`  would have solved this.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers simply point at memory addresses.  They don't remember data.  For what you are asking for, simply save the *value* of `arr[0]` to a variable before you then modify the value, eg:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    array<int, 4> arr{ 1,2,3,4 };
    int oldValue = arr[0];
    arr[0] = 5;
    cout << oldValue << endl;
    cout << arr[0] << endl;
}
```